# Facebook Posts not showing up in angular 4 using ngx-facebook and ngFor

Tags: angular, facebook

Ok this is a bit of a strange issue.
I have a service which calls the Facebook Graph API to get a list of posts on a page.
If I output the values returned to an anchor tag they show up fine and you can click on them and it will take you to the post.
If i take one of these URL and use it for the  tags href the post shows up. However, if i use ngFor to loop through the return values and use these as the URL nothing shows up. I've tried this using both a div surround the tag of the ngFor in the tag and still nothing shows up.

**Facebook post component typescript**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FacebookService, InitParams} from 'ngx-facebook';
import {FaceBookPostsService} from'../providers/facebook-graph-service.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-facebook-posts',
   templateUrl: './facebook-posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./facebook-posts.component.scss']
})
export class FacebookPostsComponent implements OnInit {


results= [];
error:any;
facebook:any;
constructor(private fb: FacebookService, private fbPost:FaceBookPostsService) {
    let initParams: InitParams = {
      appId: '***********',
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v2.8'
    };
    fb.init(initParams);


    }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fbPost.getPosts().subscribe(
      data => { this.results = data;
      console.log('values  in results');
      console.log(this.results);
      for (let i of this.results){

         console.log('url is ' + i.permalink_url);}
      },

      error => console.log(error)
    );

 }

}
```

**Face post component template**

## Our Facebook Posts

```
  <div  *ngFor="let post of  results.data">
  <fb-post  href="{{post.permalink_url}}" ></fb-post>
    <a href="{{post.permalink_url}}">{{post.permalink_url}}</a>


</div>

 <fb-post *ngFor="let post of  results.data" href="{{post.permalink_url}}"></fb-post>

  <h2> post Test</h2>
  <fb-post href="https://www.facebook.com/D2DMARYHILL/videos/169438470323930/">
 </fb-post>
```

The results of this are shown in the image below.
[image: The reuslts of our facebook post component]
As you can see the URLs are being returned, however, when they are used in the `<fb-post>` as the URL for its href attribute using an angular variable then nothing is showing up. However, if I place one of the urls and hardcode it as the href then the post is returned. This is a real head-scratcher so I'm hoping  one of you can help me resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

from what i understood, fb-post should be created at the activation of the component- I had this problem too, what I done to fix it was:

```
    <app-facebook-posts *ngIf="fbPost.your-data.length>0"></app-facebook-posts>
```

it simply call the data after it exists...
in the component you do:

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of fbPost.your-data">
      <fb-post showText="true" width="auto" [href]="item">{{item}}</fb-post>
    </div>
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There can be some issues with using interpolation for property values, due to change detection - you might find that property binding is better, i.e.:

```
<a [href]="post.permalink_url">{{post.permalink_url}}</a>
```

Comment: I tried `<fb-post [href]="post.permalink_url">{{post.permalink_url}}</fb-post>  `                                                                             but that is still not working I don't want a  link to the post  but rather the post to appear on the page via the <fb-post> tags